# How to access request object in the new dialogflow API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

In the actions on google request object I have accessToken that I'm setting via account linking

```
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "user_id",
    "accessToken": "access_token",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "lastSeen": "2018-06-05T09:52:35Z",
    "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
  },
  etc
```

My firebase function allows to look for values in the Firebase database when the intent is triggered.

```
import * as admin       from 'firebase-admin'
import * as functions   from 'firebase-functions'
import { dialogflow }   from 'actions-on-google'

const dialogApp = dialogflow();

dialogApp.intent("request_value", async (conv, {devices}) => {
    console.log(devices);
    let device_name = devices;

    const snapshot = await admin.database().ref(`/system/ecofarmTest/component/${device_name}/data`).orderByChild("timestamp").limitToFirst(1).once('value');

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        console.log("Test child timestamp " + childSnapshot.val().timestamp)
        console.log("Test child value " + childSnapshot.val().value)

        const value_object = childSnapshot.val();

        conv.ask(`The ${device_name} is ${value_object.value}.\nWould you like to check anything else?`);

        return;
    })

});

export const receiveAssistantRequest = functions.https.onRequest(dialogApp);
```

Before the API change I new how to access the request object. But now, how do I access the request object to get the accessToken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do it:

```
let access_token = conv.request.user.accessToken
```

Answer (score 2):

Once your account linking is done, you have access to your access_token with

```
conv.user.access.token
```